# HighChart probleme when changing langage

Tags: jquery, plugins, charts, highcharts, jquery-plugins

I have a Multi-language website (ar-fr) and I am using highchart type pie, when i switch language from French to Arabic I get this. Does someone have a solution to this?

I can't use `Set opposite: true` on the yAxis to move it to the right side
`Set reversed: true` on the xAxis to make it flow right to left
because i m having a types pie so data goes just with series

[image: ImageChart]

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var char = Highcharts.chart('containerPopulation', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
        ,
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} / {point.percentage:.1f}%</b><br/>',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
                name: '',
                data: <?php echo $result ?>
            }]
    });

    char.series[0].name = "";
    $('.highcharts-credits').hide();

</script>
```

Comment: When you say you are getting "this" are you referring to the image?  Can you be more clear on the error you are seeing?

Comment: i never said i had an error my problem is when i switch from french to arabic the graph become unbalanced like in the image left:fr , right: arabic.

Comment: check this [internationalization](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization)

Comment: Can you make a live example of the problem? Your starting point can be this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

Comment: here is an exemple of the problem  http://jsfiddle.net/bj5ysrcy/